# How to create a Signal or Stream which only output when the input have been stopped for a period of time?

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

How to create a Signal or Stream which only output when the input have been stopped for a period of time?

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
S1 : S - - S S S S - - - - - S S S S - - - -
S2 : - - - - - - - - - S - - - - - - - - S -
```

I would like to transform S1 into S2, which only output the last event if event has stopped for 3 - (where - is x seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `throttle:`, which waits for x seconds for another signal before sending through a next.

Comment: `throttle:` is not what I want. Throttle will produce S--S--S for SSSSSSS but not --------S.

Comment: I did check throttle. From my testing it produces a third value when put directly against my source. That might be a timing issue though.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. `throttle:` is the correct way, but in `ReactiveCocoa ` is wired.

Answer (score 0):

This is C# code, but you should be able to translate:

```
string xs = "S--SSSS-----SSSS----";
IObservable<char> source =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Zip(xs.ToCharArray(), (n, c) => c)
        .Where(c => c == 'S');

IObservable<char> query =
    source
        .Select(x =>
            Observable
                .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3.0))
                .Select(y => x))
        .Switch();
```

This produces the two values at the correct time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After googling I found what exactly I want. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html

Comment: Debounce is throttle. That's what you said to Lowly that you didn't want.

Comment: OK. I think that a naming problem with `reactive-cocoa`, throttle in `reactive-cocoa` is not like `debounce`.